Kahler differentials and etale fundamental group
In Algebraic geometry we can define two notions that generalize tools from topology/differential geometry: the etale fundamental group and the module/sheaf of Kähler differentials.
In the complex setting (ie when dealing with an affine or projective smooth complex manifold $X$), we can assume both points of view and we can also introduce the integral of a 1-form, say $\omega$, along a loop $\gamma$. If $\omega$ is closed we have homotopy invariance of the integral and, thanks to Stokes theorem, we can define a map $\int:\pi_1(X,x)×H^1_{dR}(X,\mathbb{C})\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ with nice properties.
Of course, to be precise, integration is not defined over non-smooth submanifolds in general, but we can take the homology class of $\gamma$, and it is a well known fact that in that setting the construction works.

So here's the question: does this construction of a pairing in any way generalizes when we consider $X$ as a scheme, replacing the fundamental group with its étale counterpart and holomorphic differentials with algebraic ones?
And if that is possible does this works even for more general schemes?
